# cannot boot ubuntu without usb

Tags: boot

I replace my windows 7(was not booting) to ubuntu, but now ubuntu will not start withou the usb have tried many approaches without luck, have tried reinstalling grub but still not luck boot-repair gives me a message to GPart, i am new user to ubuntu love the new system but want it to be my permanant os on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue. i had a lot of trouble installing off of the USB. and i ultimately had to rid my windows 7 to install Ubuntu.

are you sure you chose to install Ubuntu to replace windows 7?

are you sure you saved in to you c:/ drive and not the USB?

(its possible to install and run off USB stick)

did you change your system back to boot off of your hard drive in bios?

are you sure your hard drive is functioning properly?

```
in order to get mine to install properly off of the USB i had to choose the option "something else" and manually choose the hard-drive to install on.
```

let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for responding. i chose to replace windows 7, in not sure if i saved it to c:/ drive. yes i am runing ubuntu off the usb. i did change the system back to boot from hard drive, i am not sure if it is funcioning properly. i chose something else but it did not work, it says root file not found. i tried creating new partition it did install but i still cannot boot from the hard drive. i can boot with the usb pluged in, if i boot without the usb i am asked to boot from the hard drive in bios but it still boots back to the bios. i have tried boot repair, but it gives me a GTP error.

Comment: boot of your usb and follow the instructions from the previously answered question. that should work for you. if not my best guess is something went wrong with your hdd and that is why windows wasnt booting in the first place.